# how to convert the currency from DKK to the USD OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, currency

`$this->currency->convert('99.00', 'DKK', 'USD');` - not working, shows  =  99

`$this->currency->convert('99.00', 'GBP', 'USD');` -  shows  =  142.0984682675

Why to not convert the currency from DKK to the USD? 
how to do it?

Comment: Maybe this is more a question for the opencart community:  https://forum.opencart.com/ or http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=start

Comment: thank you, but  write that it should work, but it does not work